# Is there a way to generalize a component to have the props/onclick function without adding the same thing for others component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I use React + styled and my question is about the following code

```
<MobileButton
   onClick={props.handleMobileDropdownElementClicked}
   padding={isSmallDevice ? 1 : 0}
>
   Name
</MobileButton>
```

Is there a way to generalise this component to write like this without having props and onclick()? like the following code.

```
<MobileButton>
   Name
</MobileButton>
```

I was just curious if there is things in react or styled component that could do that if we are repeating the same component with the same props/onclick function.

Thank you

Comment: How would `<MobileButton>` get a value for `handleMobileDropdownElementClicked`? You have to get that in there somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can make a new component that doesn't require said props. But you'll still have to pass the props when creating that component initially.

For example:

```
const YourComponent = (props) => {
    const NewMobileButton = (newProps) => {
        return (
            <MobileButton
                onClick={props.handleMobileDropdownElementClicked}
                padding={isSmallDevice ? 1 : 0}
            >
                {newProps.children}
            </MobileButton>
        )
    }
    return (
        <>
            <NewMobileButton>1</NewMobileButton>
            <NewMobileButton>2</NewMobileButton>
        </>
    )
}
```